# C - read TXT change from dup to fgets and sscanf

Tags: c

I read from txt pairs of numbers
How check it **only 2 numbers** in each line and not 3. I want show the line is the problem for example the pairs file:

```
3
25 35
14 42
30 60 70
```

Console: illegal input at line 4

I know That's not the correct way at all. Need use fgets to read and sscanf to parse.
I tried but the memory full garbage. How can I change it correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, c;
    FILE *fp;
    char str[100];
    fp = fopen("./pairs.txt", "r");
    if (dup2(fileno(fp), STDIN_FILENO < 0))
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return -1;
    }

    if (feof(fp))
        printf("Error reading file");

    scanf("%d", &numOfPairs);
    arrNum = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numOfPairs * numbersInPair);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPairs * numbersInPair; i += 2)
    {
        int num1, num2;
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        arrNum[i] = num1;
        arrNum[i + 1] = num2;
    }
}
```

Another try NOT working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int index, i, numOfPairs;
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("./pairs.txt", "r");

    if ((c = getc(file)) == EOF)
    {
        perror("Error opening file"); //or return 1;
        fclose(file);
    }
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &numOfPairs);

        allNumbers = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numOfPairs * numbersInPair); //need multiply in 2 numbers for each pair
        while (!feof(file) && numOfPairs > 0)
        {
            int x, y, arrIndex = 0;
            numOfPairs--;
            fscanf(file, "%d %d", &x, &y);
            allNumbers[arrIndex] = x;
            printf("The X : %d\n", x);
            allNumbers[arrIndex + 1] = y;
            printf("THE Y : %d\n", y);
            arrIndex + 2;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
```

Comment: `scanf` has a return value telling you how many receiving arguments were assigned to, you should check that

Comment: Also your code is using `scanf` while the question says it should use `sscanf` - there is some obvious mismatch happening here

Comment: Aside: `if (feof(fp))` will never be `true` since there was no attempt to read from the file. Related: [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Go through the file with `fgets`. Control the loop with its return value. Then `sscanf` each line for *three* integer values. If the return value is not `2` there was a data error. `int res = sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z);`

Comment: How strict do you want the syntax check to be? Is "123 456 abc" okay? Would multiple white spaces before/between/after numbers ok?

Comment: hmmm... you say you have tried fgets and sscanf. Good but why didn't you post that code? The code posted doesn't read from the file at all. Further the `dup2` is very strange... why do you think you need it?

Comment: dup 2 the only way worked for me.. other ways was arr with garbage same as scanf